# jQuery: set the current date by default in a DateBox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to set current date for input of a DateBox control in jQuery mobile when I open the page for the first time.

My code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Driver Work Information</li>
    <li style="border: 0;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateOfRemark" runat="server" Text="Date of Remark :"></asp:Label>
        <input name="DateOfRemark" id="DateOfRemark" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"defaultValue":true}' />
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple script to Show the Current Date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    $('#DateOfRemark').val(formatDate(date));
});

function formatDate(dt)
{
    var d, y, m;
    d = dt.getDay();
    m = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    y = dt.getFullYear();
    var ret = '';
    if(d < 10)
        d = '0' + d;
    if(m < 10)
        m = '0' + m;
    ret = d + "/" + m + "/" + y;
    return ret;
}
```

this displays the Date in the format `d/M/yyyy`

Comment: var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm } today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;


    $('#DateOfRemark').val(today); I have done this but its not working

Comment: Thanxs Gokul but i have done the same thing but its not working .I think there must be some another method to set default date as this is input control with type date in jquery mobile(JQM)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you-

```
 var now = new Date();

 var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
 var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

 var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
 $('#timeDateBox').val(today);
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbVqh/270/)